# Java assigning to private int variable causes KeyListener not to fire

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a class that extends JPanel and implements KeyListener. In the constructor I have it so that a variable called fontHeight is set to a number:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);

        Foo panel = new Foo();
        jf.add(panel);

        for (;;) {
            jf.validate();
            jf.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(30);
        }
    }
}

public class Foo extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private int fontHeight;
    private String content;
    public Foo() {
        content = "";
        fontHeight = getfontMetrics(getFont()).getAscent();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        System.out.println("this works and sh*t");
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(content, 0, 13);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        content += e.getKeyCode();
    }
}
```

When I run this, it prints `it works and sh*t`. So its not getting stuck in the constructor. Its also not that its not repainting; if I add a line of code to add a character to `content` at the end of `paintComponent`, it draws the expanding string.

It works fine if I comment out the `fontHeight =` line. What I don't get is how assigning to a variable would cause the KeyListener not to function. Am I just missing something really simple here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does it work if you call `getfontMetrics(getFont()).getAscent();` and don't assign it to a variable? Maybe something about getFontMetrics is stopping it.

Comment: `String` + `int`?  Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: @Vincent I tried it without assigning and still it didn't work. It seems like its a problem with getFontMetrics as you said.

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you want the entire program?

Comment: @tsuzuki I want something that I can run, which demonstrates your problem.  Preferably as short as you can make it which demonstrates your work flow and the problem you are having

Comment: One issue could be that you should call repaint() after a key event. Otherwise, Java has no way of knowing the frame needs to be redrawn then (unless you're repainting at a fixed interval). However, I don't think this is your only problem

Comment: @Vincent I'm pretty sure its not a repaint problem, because I tried putting a `System.out.println("char pressed")` in the KeyPressed event and nothing happened when I tried typing.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(...)`? infinite for loop? No, don't do that, don't poll. Instead listen and notify.

Comment: How exactly did you get this to compile without having () in your constructor?

Comment: @tsuzuki Your `for-loop` scares me as it has the potential to block the EDT. Just because something is focusable, doesn't mean it will get focus.  Add a `MouseListener` to `Foo`, so when it's clicked, it can call `requestFocusInWindow`.  In your `keyPressed` method, add a debug statement to make sure it's been called and add a call to `repaint` to repaint the panel.  Instead of `KeyListener`, us the key bindings API which will resolve the key board focus issues

Comment: @Vincent I wrote it on the fly and I forgot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your Foo class:

```
@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

This tells it that as soon as it is added to the JFrame, it will actually request focus (instead of just being focusable). Focus is a huge pain and it makes Swing programming way more confusing than it needs to be.